# Can a built-in extension override method signatures?

Tags: typescript

When extending a "build-in" class (such as `Array`) with typescript, is there a way to override the class method signature?

For example, if I wanted to extend `Array<T>` and provide a `#concat()` method which could give me type safety (ie, only allow arrays of the same type to be concatenated), is that possible?

Here's something similar to the code I am attempting:

```
class List<T> extends Array<T> {
  public concat(...lists: T[][]): List<T> {
    // code here
  }
}
```

And here's the giant error that typescript tosses out to my editor:

```
[ts] Class 'List<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'T[]'.
  Types of property 'concat' are incompatible.
    Type '(...lists: T[][]) => List<T>' is not assignable to type '{ <U extends T[]>(...items: U[]): T[]; (...items: T[]): T[]; }'.
      Type 'List<T>' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
        Types of property 'concat' are incompatible.
          Type '(...lists: T[][]) => List<T>' is not assignable to type '{ <U extends T[]>(...items: U[]): T[]; (...items: T[]): T[]; }'.
            Types of parameters 'lists' and 'items' are incompatible.
              Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
class List<T>
```

Is there any way around this? Or am I better off just making a new method name?

Comment: Looks like it already does the check for you `<U extends T[]>(...items: U[]): T[]` means that `items` is of type `T[][]` (because `U` must extend `T[]`). Did you find a use case where it allowed you to add arrays of another type?

Comment: Oh you know what, you're right. My mistake. I think I was internally accidentally trying to extend the definition of Array<any> instead of the definition of Array<T>. Swapping to `public concat<U extends T>(...lists: U[]): List<T> { /* ... */ }` compiles without any issue.

Comment: Side note, what's the syntax with the `type` in the provided error? Does the semicolon delimit available overloads?